# consolidate column values only if same

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, string-comparison

I have a table with the following structure:

```
category | col_a | col_b
---------+-------+------
cat_1    |   1.0 | X
cat_1    |   0.0 | X
cat_1    |   1.0 | Y
cat_2    |   2.0 | Z
cat_2    |   1.0 | Z
```

Values in `col_a` (float values) need to be simply summed - no issues here. However, I want to consolidate all `col_b` (strings) values **only** if all values are the same per `category`, otherwise return `null`. So final output should be like below:

```
category | sum_a | same_or_none_b
---------+-------+---------------
cat_1    |   2.0 | null
cat_2    |   3.0 | Z
```

Can someone kindly help or direct me towards a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` expression to distinguish the two cases:

```
SELECT category,
       sum(col_a) AS sum_a,
       CASE WHEN count(DISTINCT col_b) = 1
            THEN min(col_b)
       END AS same_or_none_b
FROM tab
GROUP BY category;
```